# Javascript: Fill in a grid, one section per second

Tags: javascript, draw

I'm having trouble even getting started with this (pointers to tutorials, etc welcomed)

I'm looking to have a 10x10 grid (say 100px x 100px) that fills in one section every second until full (100 seconds):

```
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | etc...
```

One second:

```
|X| | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | etc...
```

Two seconds:

```
|X|X| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | etc...
```

Thirteen seconds:

```
|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
|X|X|X| | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | etc...
```

The fill in should be solid - or a simple icon (say a star of david)

I'm good with basic Javascript - but this is confounding me.

Comment: what is your grid made off? Are you referring to a table? a collection of divs? a canvas?

Comment: @TimothéeGroleau any/all --- though countained in a div that can be moved around the page

Comment: Some great answers. Not sure why all the downvotes? (Happy to learn how to improve the question that wont raise so much ire...)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. I used jQuery for the selector. You can use any method you wish:

**CSS**:

```
.box {
    width         : 9%;
    height        : 20px;
    border-left   : 1px solid #000;
    float         : left;
    margin-bottom : 5px;
    text-align    : center;
}
```

**JS**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)  {
    $('<div class="box" />').appendTo('body');
    setTimeout(function(i) {
        $('.box:empty:first').html('&#10017;'); // Draw Star of David
    }, (i + 1) * 1000);
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/QnYNW/

Answer (score 1):

Here, this should help you out, in plain JS:

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/esucig/1/edit

HTML:

```
<table id="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#grid, #grid td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#grid td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var colors = 'pink,cyan,orange,blue,red,lightgreen'.split(','),
    cells = document.querySelectorAll('#grid td');

function colorize(cell) {
  var color = colors.shift();
  cell.style.backgroundColor = color;
  colors.push(color);
}

[].forEach.call(cells, function(cell, i) {
  setTimeout(function(){ colorize(cell) }, 500*i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here another more general solution:

```
var gridFiller = function(rows, cols, delay, fn) {
    var currentRow = 0;
    var currentCol = 0;    

    var runner = function() {
      fn(currentRow, currentCol);
      if (!(currentRow === rows-1 && currentCol === cols-1)) {
        currentRow = ++currentRow % rows;
        if (!currentRow) {
          currentCol = ++currentCol % cols;
        }
        setTimeout(runner, delay);
      }
    };
    setTimeout(runner, delay);
};

gridFiller(10, 10, 1000, function(x, y) {
  /* Fill Grid Cell */
  console.log(x + ' / ' + y);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
timer = setInterval(functionThatFillsOnPosition, timeInMiliseconds);
```

and when you finish just call

```
clearInterval(timer)
```

see here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com).  It isn't a good idea to ever link that site here.

Comment: @Daedalus do agree with you, their almost like wikipedia but still sometimes they do a good work, like in this case... at least i believe, but will avoid refering them in the future

Comment: The page you linked suggests using a direct call to the function in the method; this is bad, as as far as I am aware, this makes it execute instantly.  The solution is to put it in an anon function within the method.

Comment: true but that is just a concept example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 myInterval = setInterval((function () {
    var count = 0;
    return function () {
        count++;
        var row = Math.floor(count / 10);
        var col = count - (row * 10);

        // fill in with row & column here

        if (count === 100) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }
}()),1000);
```